# How to plot boundary line of binary classification algorithm

Tags: classification, matlab, binary-data

I was trying to implement a binary classification in Matlab using this $$ \sum_{k=1}^m(y_i-W^{T}*x)^2 $$ loss function which weights can be calculated from this  $$W^{T} =  \sum_{k=1}^m(y_i*x_i^{T}) * (\sum_{k=1}^m(x_i*x_i^{T}))^{-1}   $$
after I calculate weights in matlab I wanted to draw boundry line which seperate my two inputs classess, however the result line doesn't seems to be correct
here is my matlab code:

```
clear;
clc;
close all;
%number of test cases
data_size = 10;
features = 2;
[x1,x2] = ginput(data_size);
y = zeros(data_size,0);
% I assumed first 5 inputs are one class and the others are in the other class
for i=1:data_size
    if i <= 5
       y(i) = 1;
    else
       y(i) =-1;
    end
end
x = x1;
x(1:data_size,3) = 1;
x(1:data_size,2) = x2;
first_sigma = y(1) * x(1,:);
for i=2:data_size
    first_sigma = first_sigma + (y(i) * x(i,:));
end
second_sigma =  transpose(x(1,:)) * x(1,:);
for i=2:data_size
    second_sigma = second_sigma + transpose(x(1,:)) * x(1,:);
end
weight = first_sigma/second_sigma;
slope = -(weight(3)/weight(2))/(weight(3)/weight(1));
intercept = -weight(3)/weight(2);
new_x = 0.1:0.01:1;
new_y = new_x*slope + intercept;
figure
scatter(x1,x2,25,y,'filled');
hold on
plot(new_x,new_y);
hold off
```

I am wondering where is the problem here I checked my code with formula and all seems to be correct however ploted line is wrong

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that $y_i$ are $0,1$ (and that you insist on the strange choice of RMS error vs binary logistic), you'll need to define some kind of rules for determining how to round $Wx$ to either $0$ or 1. One possibility is to require that the prediction is 0 if $Wx\leq r$ and $1$ if $Wx>r$, where $r$ is some value between 0 and 1. Then your boundary will be defined by the set of $x$ that satisfy $Wx-r=0$